# Не могу разобраться с зависимостями в гемфайле

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

изучаю новый проект, есть гемсет, версия ruby-2.0.0

Делаю bundle, выдает ошибку

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Nokogiri в гемфайле нет, нашел гемы которые его устанавливают. Прописываю в гемфайле

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8.1'
```

Гемы которые его устанавливают я комментирую. Делаю bundle, все норм. Потом я раскоментировал остальные гемы. Теперь все проходит.

1) В принципе так можно делать? Чем это черевато?

2) Может лучше поменять версию ruby? чем это черевато?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Нет, нельзя.

Перед запуском кода приложения нужно, чтобы `bundle` прошёл на той же версии `Gemfile`, с которой запускается код.

Тут одно из двух:

- либо в гемфайле действительно лишние записи и их нужно выкинуть

  - Или перераспределить по группам. Если какие-то нужны только для тестирования, их отсутствие не помешает работе и разработке (хотя разработка без тестов в мире Ruby считается безумием), но тесты упадут.
- либо они нужны и всё-таки надо разобраться, что мешает установке (скорее это)

  - [На сайте Nokogiri исчерпывающая инструкция](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html).

Зачем вообще нужен `Gemfile`, если игнорировать то, что в нём написано, и устанавливать зависимости только частично?

Разумеется, отвалится всё, что опирается на `nokogiri`, как только попытается его загрузить. А Nokogiri занимается практически всем, что связано с разбором XML и HTML, например с "дезинфекцией" (sanitization) HTML-кода от пользователей.

В данном конкретном случае Nokogiri прямо говорит, что ему не нравится:

```
nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
```

Версия Ruby, она ниже 2.1.0. Обновление Ruby должно устранить как минимум эту проблему, хотя другие тоже могут возникнуть.

Если вы поднимаете чужой проект, лучше не трогайте гемфайл вообще, постарайтесь воспроизвести среду, в особенности то, что указано в `Gemfile.lock`. Если этого файла нет, то проект почти однозначно потребует починки.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что установке мешает то, что подтягивается версия nokogiri 1.7.0.1, а для этой версии нужна версия ruby >= 2.1.0. Но в гемсете указана версия ruby-2.0.0-p247. Что лучше сделать в такой ситуации?

Comment: @dmitriy эм. Да, нужно явно быть мной, чтобы пропустить надпись `requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0`. Сейчас поправлю ответ. Извините .-. Да, должно помочь.

Comment: Грубо говоря, в rvm установить версию ruby-2.2.4, например. И находясь в проекте сделать bundle? Это и значит обновить версию ruby? или еще что-то сделать нужно. Просто это первое что я сделал и посыпались другие ошибки.

Comment: @dmitriy нужно ещё переключиться на неё через `rvm use`. То, что посыпались другие ошибки, может означать наличие не только этой, но и других проблем.

Comment: Ну да, спасибо. С остальными ошибками буду разбираться по мере поступления. А в файле .ruby-version нужно версию поменять?

Comment: @dmitriy ну, если в репозитории её не было, стоит удалить этот файл вообще, пока проект не поднимется.

Comment: да нет, я клонировал проект из репозитория. Там уже есть этот файл вместе с .ruby-gemset

Comment: @dmitriy тогда оставьте то, что там есть сейчас. Или там указано 2.0.0?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53146/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-d-side).